# Sed replace pattern with file contents

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I would like to use `sed` (I think?) to replace a pattern with file contents.

## Example

### File 1 (primary file)

```
Hello <<CODE>>
Goodbye.
```

### File 2 (contents)

```
Anonymous person,
I am very nice.
```

### File 3 (target)

```
Hello Anonymous person,
I am very nice.
Goodbye.
```

---

Right now, I am using this command:

```
sed "/<<CODE>>/{r file2
:a;n;ba}" file1            | \
    sed "s/<<CODE>>//g"    > \
    file3
```

But this outputs:

```
Hello
Anonymous person,
I am very nice.
Goodbye.
```

(note the newline after `Hello`)

- How can I do this without getting that newline?

  - (note that `file2` may contain all sorts of things: brackets, newlines, quotes, ...)

Comment: Does it have to be `sed`?  Could you use `perl` or `ruby` or `python`?

Comment: The rest of the script is in `bash`, so anything that doesn't require calling/creating a new (script)file is appreciated.

Comment: but a oneliner perl or ruby command could work, right?

Comment: If you know how to write it, then yes :-). My knowledge of `perl` / `ruby` is limited.

Comment: I'm still thinking.  I'm not sure if perl/ruby is better, but it seems like it might open things up a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much simpler to use awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{s=(!s)?$0:s RS $0;next} /<<CODE>>/{sub(/<<CODE>>/, s)} 1' file2 file1
Hello Anonymous person,
I am very nice.
Goodbye.
```

**Explanation:**

- `FNR==NR` - Execute this block for first file in input i.e. `file2`
- `s=(!s)?$0:s RS $0` - Concatenate whole file content in string `s`
- `next` - Read next line until `EOF` on first file
- `/<<CODE>>/` - If a line with `<<CODE>>` is found execute that block
- `sub(/<<CODE>>/, s)` - Replace `<<CODE>>` with string `s` (data of `file2`)
- `1` - print the output

---

**EDIT:** Non-regex way:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{s=(!s)?$0:s RS $0; next}
     i=index($0, "<<CODE>>"){$0=substr($0, 1, i-1) s substr($0, i+8)} 1' file2 file1
```

Comment: I think you and I have a different definition of simple ;-). Still, it works flawlessly.

Comment: @EtienneBruines: lol :) Hope my explanation will bring our definitions closer. Feel free to ask any question to explain further.

Comment: This does break on using the `&`-character (i.e.: the `&`-character is being replaced by `<<CODE>>`)

Comment: file2. Just found out `sed` requires me to escape `&`-character. Maybe that's related.

Answer (score 1):

The `awk` though it might be harder to read, is probably the right way to go.

Just for comparison sake, here's a ruby version

```
ruby -ne 'BEGIN{@body=File.open("file2").read}; puts gsub(/<<CODE>>/,@body);' < file1
```

Answer (score 1):

not too bad in `Perl`:

```
 cat file1 | perl -e "open FH, qq(file2); \$f2=join '', <FH>; chomp \$f2; map {s/<<CODE>>/\$f2/g; print \$_} <STDIN>" > file3
```

(maybe i am not the best perl coder)

it's straight-forward. read the whole file2 in, substitute it, then print.

Answer (score 1):

You could do simply with:

```
awk '{gsub("<<CODE>>", filetwo)}1' filetwo="$(<file2)" file1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking about a solution where we use Bash to evaluate a `cat` process outside of the single quotes delimitating the `sed` script, but unfortunately the following doesn't work as soon as your `file2` contains a newline:

```
sed 's/<<CODE>>/'"$(cat file2)"'/' file1
```

It accepts spaces in `file2`, but not newlines, as you can see in the following piece of code that works well, whatever the content of `file2`:

```
sed 's/<<CODE>>/'"$(cat file2 | tr -d '\n')"'/' file1
```

But, obviously, this modifies the content of the file before inclusion, which is simply bad. :-(

So if you want to play, you can first `tr` the newlines to some weird unexpectable character, and translate those back after `sed` has worked on its script:

```
sed 's/<<CODE>>/'"$(cat file2 | tr '\n' '\3')"'/' file1 | tr '\3' '\n'
```